# Ways to accurate synchronize clock with linux

Tags: linux, sync, time, ntp

I have a computer that doesn't has internet, I put NTP to sync with a USB GPS and serve NTP to other computers. That's working, but sometimes the server is not suitable for synchronization and I need that times between computers are not more than 100ms desynchronized, because I have triggers that get references by time.
Computer are all in local network and sometimes I need to call ntpdate several times until get offset lower (e.g. below).

```
15 Jul 15:25:07 ntpdate[10755]: adjust time server 192.168.0.10 offset -0.147476 sec
15 Jul 15:25:16 ntpdate[10811]: adjust time server 192.168.0.10 offset -0.144538 sec
15 Jul 15:25:25 ntpdate[10815]: adjust time server 192.168.0.10 offset -0.142689 sec
15 Jul 15:26:07 ntpdate[10875]: adjust time server 192.168.0.10 offset -0.126713 sec
15 Jul 15:26:18 ntpdate[10878]: adjust time server 192.168.0.10 offset -0.122535 sec
```

The question is: Is there a way to get my computers synchronized faster and with accuracy? With NTP or which tool is better?

Comment: Is this a local network?

Comment: @DanielB yes, it is

Comment: @JohnJob why can't you just run `ntp` normally rather than calling `ntpdate` (Which is depreciated)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an alternative to ntp is chrony.
https://chrony.tuxfamily.org/comparison.html

Comment: Thanks, resolved with chrony